# vim scriptでインデントがしたい

Tags: vim

次の8行だけのvimrcを書きました。

```
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
function! F()
    >>
endfunction
nmap z :<C-u>call F()<CR>
```

zキーを押すと、半角スペース4個分インデントされる事を期待したいのですが、結果は2倍の8個分インデントされてしまいました。

ノーマルモードで>>やインサートモードでtabキーを押すと、半角スペース4個分インデントされました。
vimrcで定義したF関数の>>でインデントする時のみ、shiftwidthの2倍の幅でインデントされてしまいます。

shiftwidthに設定した幅でインデントさせる方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:h vimrc`すると以下の記述があります。

```
vimrcファイルは一行ずつExコマンドとして実行される。
```

`:h Ex`すると以下の記述があります。

```
このモードは ":" コマンドを続けて入力するようなもの...
```

つまり`.vimrc`は各行に ":" が暗黙的についていることになります。
これを踏まえると `>>` という行は `:>`を2回おこなうという指示になります。(`:h :>`)
ですので'shiftwidth' 2個分右にズレるのです。
ノーマルコマンドの`>>`とは異なります。(`:h >>`)
ノーマルコマンドを実行させたい場合は明示的に`normal!`を指定します。(`:h normal`)
(`!`を付けているのは他でmapされた`>>`を使わず本来の`>>`を使うようにするためです)

```
normal! >>
```

これで'shiftwidth' 1個分インデントされます。
もちろんExコマンドとして

```
>
```

でも構いません。